# Is compund multivariate derivation a summation along all paths in dependency graph?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, chain-rule

The multivariate chain rule can be succinctly expressed as 
$$\frac{df}{dy} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dy}$$
if $f = f(y, z)$ is a function of $y$ and $z$, and $z=z(y)$ a function of $y$.

Now, suppose many more functional dependencies are involved. For simplicity, suppose we're try to derive $\frac{dh}{dx}$, where $h=h(f, g)$, $g=g(f, x)$ and $f=f(x)$. The functional dependencies between these variables can be expressed by the following graph,

[image]

Gathering the change in each variable due to the one(s) preceding it, the desired derivative can be expressed as,
$$
(\star) \quad
\frac{dh}{dx} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial g}\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial h}{\partial g}\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\cdot\frac{df}{dx} +
\frac{\partial h}{\partial f}\cdot \frac{df}{dx}
$$

One could interpret $(\star)$ as a summation over all *paths* from $x$ to $h$ in the dependency graph, where each path contributes the product of partial derivatives along its edges. e.g., the path $x\to f\to g\to h$ contributes the expression $\frac{\partial h}{\partial g}\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\cdot\frac{df}{dx}$ to the summation at $(\star)$.

### Questions

1. Is the identity $(\star)$ indeed correct?
2. Having in mind more complicated dependency graphs, can a derivative between two nodes indeed be considered as a summation over all paths connecting them, as above? It could be nice to have proof, if so.

Comment: I believe you would need to expand your notation to account for the cases such as $g(x, y)$ composed with $f(x)$ to give you beasts such as $g(f(x),f(x))$.

Comment: Yes -- perhaps a notation such as $\partial_1 g$ and $\partial_2 g$ could then be used. By the intentions at the question are clear, aren't they?